# How to make server start with couchase server down?

Tags: java, spring-data-couchbase

My project use spring-data-couchbase 2.x.

We use Couchbase as a caching layer only and would expect the service works fine even if couchbase is down.

However, I would get exceptions during server startup for bean injections.

Is there anyway I can ignore failure of connection initialization?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle such errors like below and it will not let your program fail.

```
@Configuration
public class CouchbaseConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

@Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new CacheErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
                logger.warn(cache.getName(), exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
                logger.warn(cache.getName(), exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
                logger.warn(cache.getName(), exception);
            }

            @Override
            public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
                logger.warn(cache.getName(), exception);
            }
        };
    }
}
```